# Detached threads don't run simultaneously

Tags: c, multithreading

Hey so I'm trying to create a multithreaded program. The first thread takes in input from std in and stores it in a minheap. The second thread... well for now, all it does is print "sequencer thread works" and nothing else because it doesn't run properly.

Both threads are detached, so they should run simultaneously, and yet for some reason the second thread doesn't run until the first exits. Is it something simple I am overlooking? I'm new to multithreading.

Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "MinHeap.h"


pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;



void* readerthread(MinHeap minheap, char eventlist[], char timestamp[])
{
    char buffer[100];
    char input;
    int ret, len, fd;



    while(1)
    {
        char *choice;
        choice = malloc(50*sizeof(char));


        fgets(choice, 50, stdin);
        printf("choice = : %s", choice);
        if(checkTimestamp(choice)==0)
        {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        addElement(&minheap, choice);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }
        free(choice);
        printf( "min of minheap: %s\n", getMin(&minheap));


}

void* sequencerthread()
{
    printf("sequencer works\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argv < 2)
    {
        printf("not enough arguments. exiting...\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char timestamp[50];
    char event[50];
    char eventlist[sizeof(char)+170];
    int i;

    char nowtimestamp[] = "2400/001/00/00/00";


    MinHeap minheap;
    initializeMinHeap(&minheap, intCompare, sizeof(char)*50);

    strcpy(timestamp, argv[1]);
    strcpy(event, argv[2]);



    pthread_t ignore1, ignore2;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    pthread_attr_setscope(&attr, PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM);

    pthread_create(&ignore1, &attr, readerthread(minheap, eventlist, nowtimestamp), 0);
    pthread_create(&ignore2, &attr, sequencerthread, 0);

    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
    pthread_exit(0);



    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
```

Comment: Whether the threads are detached has nothing in particular to do with whether they run concurrently.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I thought joined threads, execute sequentially? Isn't that what pthread_join() does?

Comment: No.  In the first place, the distinction is not between join*ed* threads and detached ones, it's between join*able* threads and detached ones.  In the second place, all threads in a process run concurrently as long as they are not blocked.  `pthread_join()` makes the **calling** thread wait for the specified one to terminate (one way in which a thread can be blocked), but it does not affect the concurrency of other threads.  In particular, if your main thread joined the other two, that would not prevent those other two from running concurrently with each other.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ahhhh, thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
pthread_create(&ignore1, &attr, readerthread(minheap, eventlist, nowtimestamp), 0);
```

You're calling `readerthread` *on the main thread* and passing its *result* to `pthread_create`.  Since `readerthread` never returns, you never even get to the first call to `pthread_create`, let alone the second one.

You need to call it like this instead:

```
pthread_create(&ignore1, &attr, readerthread, &readerthread_args);
```

where `readerthread_args` is a struct encapsulating the arguments to pass to `readerthread`.  You'll also need to change `readerthread` to take a single `void *` argument, cast it to the type of `readerthread_args`, and unpack the args.

You should have got a whole bunch of warnings from your compiler.  Did you remember to turn them on?

Comment: That makes total sense. Thank you, this is my first attempt at multithreading. I should have noticed all the example code didn't pass arguments the way I did. The warnings I was getting were all unrelated to the threads, though.

Comment: You should get in the habit of fixing all warnings (compiling with -Werror in gcc helps). Warnings are there for a reason.